# Freemarker custom method - get ModelAndView without explicitely passing it

Tags: freemarker

I have written my own url routing mechanism, which allows mapping URLs to ModelAndViews and ModelAndViews back to URL (https://github.com/knyttl/Maite/wiki/Maite-Routing).

I am trying to create a Freemarker method which would modify the current ModelAndView and call the reverse routing process.

So in the template I would like to achieve something like:

```
 ${link("view", [id:10, page:1])}
```

Then the macro would be defined something like:

```
@Autowired
HandlerAdapter ha;

public TemplateModel exec(List args) throws TemplateModelException {
    ModelAndView current = __getItSomehowFromTheTemplate();
    if (current.getViewName() != (String) args.get(0)) {
         // if the view is the same, we just modify the model
         ... 
         current.set...
    } else {
         // the view is different, we create a new ModelAndView
         current = new ModelAndView();
    }

    // reverse routing process
    return new SimpleScalar(ha.constructUrl(current));
}
```

I wonder whether I have to pass the ModelAndView to the method each time or I can let Freemarker somehow pass it automatically like with my magic method __getItSomehowFromTheTemplate();

If I have to pass it automatically, how can I do that? I did not find any direct reference to the current ModelAndView.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you get the current `ModelAndView` in a template? From the data-model (template context) maybe? Because then you could call `Environment.getCurrentEnvironment().getDataModel().get("theVariableName")` to get it. (See: http://freemarker.org/docs/api/freemarker/core/Environment.html)